# "Cannot resolve symbol 'glassfish'" after the first step of jersey.java.net tutorial

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, glassfish

Following the tutorial here https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/getting-started.html

I added the repository reference in the parent POM file. Then I ran this command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=com.dc.rest -DartifactId=dc-rest -Dpackage=com.dc.rest -DarchetypeVersion=2.22.1
```

When I open the project and go into the `Main` class, there are a lot of red marks with the imports giving the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'glassfish'` for `import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer`.

I've tried running these commands, but the problem continues:

```
mvn clean install
mvn idea:idea
mvn -U install
```

The clean install completes with no errors.

I've verified that I'm using Maven 3.3.3 in IntelliJ settings.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help?

**auto-generated pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.dc</groupId>
        <artifactId>dc</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dc.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>dc-rest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dc-rest</name>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshot-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Snapshot Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.dc.rest.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**versions**

```
D:\git\dc>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T05:57:37-06:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows server 2008 r2", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

D:\git\dc>java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```